# pyinstaller bundling a python application using openopc not work outside the developed machine

Tags: python-3.x, opc

I'm using the following syntex to create a successful exe that works properly on the development machine (has python installed, the project is using venv)

```
    pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --paths "C:/Users/Userxx/source/repos/PythonOPCClient/PythonOPCClient/env/Lib/site-packages" --hidden-import "win32timezone"  "C:/Users/Userxx/source/repos/PythonOPCClient/PythonOPCClient/PythonOPCClient.py"
```

The problem comes running the exe on a customer machine (No python), the application throws the following exceptions

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "OpenOPC.py", line 1117, in servers
      File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8l82ug16\gen_py\28E68F91-8D75-11D1-8DC3-3C302A000000x0x1x0.py", line 262, in GetOPCServers
        return self._ApplyTypes_(1610743825, 1, (12, 0), ((12, 17),), 'GetOPCServers', None,Node
      File "win32com\client\__init__.py", line 572, in _ApplyTypes_
    pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, 'Invalid value for registry\r\n', None, 0, -2147467259), None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PythonOPCClient.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "OpenOPC.py", line 1123, in servers
OpenOPC.OPCError: servers: -2147467259
[12352] Failed to execute script 'PythonOPCClient' due to unhandled exception!
```

using the following

- python 3.9 32-bit
- auto-py-to-exe 32-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the issue reported, it was suggested that the OPC Core Components may need to be re-installed. However, the attempt to resolve the problem using the OPC Core Components Redistributable (x86) 3.00.108.msi did not yield the desired result.

As a workaround, the Wonderware OI-gateway drive was re-installed on the affected machine, which resulted in the successful functioning of the OPCClient.

While this solution may not be a definitive fix, it is hoped that it may prove helpful to others experiencing similar issues.